# WPF - Update Datagrid in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

My datagrid view doesn't update when the source is modified.

In my View.xaml :

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Width="*" Binding="{Binding ProductHistoryInOutDate}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantité" Width="*" Binding="{Binding ProductHistoryQuantity}" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In my ViewModel.cs :

```
private ObservableCollection<ProductHistory> _Items;

public ObservableCollection<ProductHistory> Items
{
    get { return _Items; }
    set 
    { 
         _Items = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}
```

[Edit]

Command:

```
public RelayCommand Remove
{
    get
    {
        if (_Remove == null)
        {
            _Remove = new RelayCommand(
                () => { _UOF.ProductHistoryRepository.Delete(this.SelectedItem);_UOF.Commit(); },
                () => SelectedItem != null);
        }

        return _Remove;
    }
}
```

Remove button:

```
<Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=Remove}" />
```

Comment: probably you have to null out the itemsource first...

Comment: Could you give some more details? In what way is the source modified: is the entire collection changed, is item added/removed, or is a ProductHistory modified in place. Can you post the code that shows how  Items are modified?

Comment: When I remove a ProductHistory.
     
     public RelayCommand Remove
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Remove == null)
                {
                    _Remove = new RelayCommand(() =>
                    {
                        _UOF.ProductHistoryRepository.Delete(this.SelectedItem);
                        _UOF.Commit();
                    }, () => SelectedItem != null);
                }
                return _Remove;
            }
        }


     <Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=Remove}" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only explanation I can think of is that you are missing `Items.Remove(this.SelectedItem)` in your command execute code.

I tried making and example from your code and it worked fine if I added this, there was no issue with observable collection.

Since I don't have your code for RelayCommand and RaisePropertyChanged(), I had to manually implement it to try it out, but I assume it is from some library and it works fine.

Here is what it should look like:

```
public RelayCommand Remove
{
    get
    {
        if (_Remove == null)
        {
            _Remove = new RelayCommand(
                () => { Items.Remove(this.SelectedItem); _UOF.ProductHistoryRepository.Delete(this.SelectedItem); _UOF.Commit(); },
                () => SelectedItem != null);
        }

        return _Remove;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wooooow! MrZli I love you! hahaha 

I understand my miskate! Thank you so much!